# Update ctx.textAlign with js function

Tags: javascript, canvas

Hi I have this js function:

```
function ChangeTextAlign(selectTag) {
    // Returns the index of the selected option
    var whichSelected = selectTag.selectedIndex;

    // Returns the text of the selected option
    var alignValue = selectTag.options[whichSelected].text;

    var div = document.getElementById("first-text");
    div.style.textAlign = alignValue;
}
```

This function updates text alignement perfectly in the input field right there:

```
<input type='text' value='Pirma eilutė' id='first-text' />
```

But how to make it work with ctx.textAlign ? Here's how it is set right now:

```
 ctx.font = '12pt sans-serif';
 ctx.strokeStyle = '#929292';
 ctx.fillStyle = '#929292';
 ctx.textAlign = 'center';
 ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
```

I want to update the ctx.textAlign value everytime I press one of these options:

Change textAlign value:

```
 <select onchange="ChangeTextAlign (this);" size="4">
     <option />left
     <option />right
     <option selected="selected" />center
     <option />justify
 </select>
```

This works only with my input field, but I want to update the value of the ctx.textAlign. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Given this html:**

```
<select id='align' size="4">
    <option value='left'/>left
    <option value='right'/>right
    <option value='center' selected="selected" />center
    <option value='justify' />justify
</select>
```

**Listen for `change` events on your select element:**

```
var selection=document.getElementById('align');
selection.onchange=function(e){ChangeTextAlign(e);};
```

**On selection change:**

- Fetch the user's chosen alignment value
- Set `context.textAlign` to that value
- Clear the canvas
- Redraw the text to display it with the chosen alignment

The javascript `change` handler:

```
function ChangeTextAlign(event){
    var newAlignment=selection.value;
    if(newAlignment=='justify'){alert('Justify is not supported'); return;}
    ctx.textAlign=newAlignment;
    redraw(text);
}
```

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw = canvas.width;
var ch = canvas.height;

var text = 'Hello, World!'
ctx.textAlign = 'center';

redraw(text);

var selection = document.getElementById('align');
selection.onchange = function(e) {
  ChangeTextAlign(e);
};

function ChangeTextAlign(event) {
  var newAlignment = selection.value;
  if (newAlignment == 'justify') {
    alert('Justify is not supported');
    return;
  }
  ctx.textAlign = newAlignment;
  redraw(text);
}

function redraw(text) {
  // clear the canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  // demo only, show the fillText x,y
  ctx.fillRect(cw / 2, 0, 1, ch);
  // draw the text
  ctx.fillText(text, cw / 2, ch / 2);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: ivory;
}
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=200 height=100></canvas>
<select id='align' size="4">
  <option value='left' />left
  <option value='right' />right
  <option value='center' selected="selected" />center
  <option value='justify' />justify
</select>
```